# C int datatype and its variations

Tags: c, variables, types, int

Greetings , and again today when i was experimenting on language C in C99 standard , i came across a problem which i cannot comprehend and need expert's help.

**The Code:**

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
   {
    int Fnum = 256; /* The First number to be printed out */

    printf("The number %d in long long specifier is %lld\n" , Fnum , Fnum);

    return 0;
   }
```

**The Question:**

1.)This code prompted me an warning message when i try to run this code.

2.)But the strange thing is , when I try to change the specifier `%lld` to `%hd` or `%ld`,
   the warning message were not shown during execution and the value printed out on the   console is the correct digit *256* , everything also seems to be normal even if i try with
`%u` , `%hu` and also `%lu`.In short the warning message and the wrong printing of digit only happen when I use the variation of long long specifier.

3.)Why is this happening??I thought the memory size for long long is large enough to hold the value *256* , but why it cannot be used to print out the appropriate value??

**The Warning Message :(For the above source code)**

```
C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Pelles C Projects\Test1\Test.c(7): warning #2234: Argument 3 to 'printf' does not match the format string; expected 'long long int' but found 'int'.
```

Thanks for spending time reading my question.God bless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three things going on here.

1. `printf` takes a variable number of arguments.  That means the compiler doesn't know what type the arguments (beyond the format string) are supposed to be.  So it can't convert them to an appropriate type.
2. For historical reasons, however, integer types smaller than `int` are "promoted" to `int` when passed in a variable argument list.
3. You appear to be using Windows.  On Windows, `int` and `long` are the same size, even when pointers are 64 bits wide (this is a willful violation of C89 on Microsoft's part - they actually forced the standard to be changed in C99 to make it "okay").

The upshot of all this is:  The compiler is not allowed to convert your `int` to a `long long` just because you used `%lld` in the argument list.  (It is allowed to warn you that you forgot the cast, because warnings are outside standard behavior.)  With `%lld`, therefore, your program doesn't work.  But if you use any *other* size specifier, `printf` winds up looking for an argument the same size as `int` and it works.

Comment: `int` and `long` being the same size on 64-bit machines does not violate C89, which makes no guarantees about the relative sizes of integer versus pointer types or the ability of any integer types to hold pointer values or vice versa. I agree MS was insane to make `long` 32 bits on 64-bit machines, but it's purely a matter of (in)sane implementation choices, not conformance. MS has plenty of other areas where they flagrantly violate the standards but this is not one of them.

Comment: The violation of C89 may not be obvious, but I assure you it is there. C89 requires all of: `ptrdiff_t` can represent the difference between any two pointers (as long as they point into the same array); `size_t` can represent the size of any object; `sizeof(size_t) <= sizeof(long)`; and `sizeof(ptrdiff_t) <= sizeof(long)`. If you have flat pointers - which Win64 does - then the only way for all of those assertions to hold is for `sizeof(void*) <= sizeof(long)`. It is actually more of a problem that Win64 `size_t` can't represent the size of any object than that `long` can't hold a pointer IMO.

Comment: And the sad thing is, MS rammed a change into C99 (specifically, that `sizeof(size_t)` did not have to be smaller than `sizeof(long)`) and then **left `size_t` at 32 bits in Win64**. So we're stuck with bullshit like `intmax_t` in C99, but the company that wanted the license it provided didn't bother making use of it. They should have just flat out refused to conform to C99, withdrawn from the standards process, and then at least the standard wouldn't have this baggage.

Comment: This is not a violation; it just means the implementation cannot support creating any objects (including via `malloc`) larger than 2GB. Of course if the compiler does allow you to create larger objects, **that** is a violation. And keep in mind many 32-bit implementations commit this violation by allowing allocations slightly larger than 2GB even though `ptrdiff_t` cannot hold differences that large.

Comment: @Zack: `intmax_t` is pretty important regardless of the size of `size_t` unless you want a requirement that no extended integer types larger than `long long` can exist...

Comment: "If you have flat pointers - which Win64 does - then the only way for all of those assertions to hold is for sizeof(void*) <= sizeof(long)." - no, having flat pointers does not mean you can have an object or an array that is as large as the entire pointer address space. If you have no such object, then size_t/ptrdiff_t does not need to be so large.

Comment: I don't have a Win64 dev box to try it on, but I'm quite confident it does allow the creation of objects bigger than `size_t` can represent. (Otherwise what would the point of `SIZE_T`, or however their nonstandard thing that you're supposed to use instead is spelled, be?) Also, C89 truly did require that there were no integer types---not just no "extended" integer types; it didn't have that concept---larger than `long`. I was there for the arguments about this during the C99 process and I remember.

Comment: It's impossible to create an object with a size larger than `size_t` using `malloc()`, since `size_t` is the type of the argument to that function.  As long as the implementation doesn't let you create static or auto objects that large, then it's fine - any operating-specific function for creating larger objects necessarily leaves the behaviour of the program entirely undefined.

Answer (score 6):

You're passing the `Fnum` variable to printf, which is typed `int`, but it's expecting `long long`. This has very little to do with whether a long long *can* hold 256, just that the variable you chose is typed `int`.

If you just want to print 256, you can get a constant that's typed to `unsigned long long` as follows:

```
printf("The number %d in long long specifier is %lld\n" ,256 , 256ULL);
```

or cast:

```
printf("The number %d in long long specifier is %lld\n" , Fnum , (long long int)Fnum);
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with a variadic function, the caller and callee need some way of agreeing the types of the variable arguments. In the case of printf, this is done via the format string. GCC is clever enough to read the format string itself and work out whether printf will interpret the arguments in the same way as they have been actually provided.

You can get away with slightly different types of arguments in some cases. For example, if you pass a short then it gets implicitly converted to an int. And when sizeof(int) == sizeof(long int) then there is also no distinction. But sizeof(int) != sizeof(long long int) so the parameter fails to match the format string in that case.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way [varargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varargs) work in C.  Unlike a normal function, `printf()` can take any number of arguments.  It is up to the programmer to tell `printf()` what to expect by providing a correct format string.

Internally, `printf()` uses the format specifiers to access the raw memory that corresponds to the input arguments.  If you specify `%lld`, it will try to access a 64-bit chunk of memory (on Windows) and interpret what it finds as a `long long int`.  However, you've only provided a 32-bit argument, so the result would be undefined (it will combine your 32-bit `int` with whatever random garbage happens to appear next on the stack).